# Use key name into associated value with dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to know if there's a way to use a key name as a value of an inside field in associated dictionary :

```
_columns_specs = {
        'id': {
            'name': this.key.name,
            'type_': Integer,
            'primary_key': True
        }
}
```

Something like this. I would like to replace the following line :

```
'name': this.key.name,
```

Thanks for all !

Comment: what is `this.key` ?

Comment: Can you give a clear example of what you mean? Or explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want that name = 'id' (the name of the associated key)

Comment: Then why not simply write `'name': 'id'`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's what i've done, but i wanted that it was dependant of the key name.

Comment: Then `{key_name: { 'name': key_name, 'type':.....} ... }` ??

Comment: This question is too unclear. Please describe thoroughly what you want to do and why. Show us example input and output and tell us about your actual goals.

Comment: It also sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the 'name' attribute after the dictionary was created:

```
_columns_specs = {
        'id': {
            'type_': int,
            'primary_key': True
        }
}

for k, v in _columns_specs.items():
  v['name'] = k
  _columns_specs[k] = v

print (_columns_specs)
```

Returns:

```
{'id': {'type_': <class 'int'>, 'primary_key': True, 'name': 'id'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this :

```
_columns_specs['id']['name'] = 'name'
```

You can get keys with : `dictionary.keys()`

You can get values with : `dictionary.values()`

Comment: I fail to see how it's relevant. What about the "... of an inside field" part of the OP's question?